# Google plus share not showing on profile stream

Tags: google-plus

Strange that in my own testing site (https://adzbuzz.000webhostapp.com/shares/71/congo-government-allegedly-shuts-off-internet-service-to-squash-protests ) with the same codes of http://staging4.adzbuzz.com/shares/118/congo-government-allegedly-shuts-off-internet-service-to-squash-protests, the google share is working fined on the testing site while on staging site the shared post does not exist in the google plus stream after being shared.

I share the url using the plus.google.com/share?url={URL} (with https) format from my sites.

```
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={{CURRENT_URL}}" class="social-share" title="Share on Google+">
                <span class="fa fa-google-plus-official"></span>
                <span class="like-text">Google+</span>
            </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.sharePopup = function (e, width, height) {
        // Prevent default anchor event
        e.preventDefault();
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
          top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
        var strTitle = ((typeof this.attr('title') !== 'undefined') ? this.attr('title') : 'Social Share');
    window.open( this.attr('href'), strTitle,
    "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left
      );
    }
    $('.comment a.social-share').on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).sharePopup(e, 600, 400);
    });
</script>
```

Anyone has idea on how to fixed it, since even the Google+ Help community doesn't replied to this inquiry/question?

Comment: It would help if you posted some of the code; maybe just the bit that does the google share action?

Comment: Hello @miltonb i just updated my question, i think i dont have problem in my codes since it working on my testing site... i think the issue persist only  on the domain adzbuzz.com including its subdomain, although i can't confirm it..